# How to run Python top level/interpreter with file input?

Tags: python

Say I had a Python file, and I wanted to run it in the top level, but after it finishes, I want to pick up where it leaves off. I want to be able to use the objects it creates, etc.

A simple example, let's say I have a Python script that does `i = 5`. When the script ends, I want to be returned to the top level and be able to continue with `i = 5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, the -i switch is what you're looking for:

```
~$ echo "i = 5" > start.py
~$ python -i start.py 
>>> i
5
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm embarrassed to say that I don't know this after writing about a year worth of python. Is this in the python docs somewhere? I could not find it for the life of me.

Comment: `python -h` shows, among other things, """-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
"""

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're looking for [execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=execfile#execfile) - for example:

```
$ cat >seti.py
i = 5
^C
$ cat >useit.py
execfile('seti.py')
print i
$ python useit.py 
5
$
```

Comment: This is actually useful as well, I used to execute other python files using sys calls, and couldn't find on google how to do this either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`python -i` or the [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, 'python -i ' is the closest answer to your question.  You can also use 'import' to run scripts in the interpreter.  For example, if you're editing "testscript.py" you could do:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 Xxxx None    771 2009-02-07 18:26 testscript.py
$ python
>>> import testscript
>>> print testlist
['result1', 'result2']
>>>
```

testscript.py has to be in sys.path for this to work (sys.path includes the current working directory automatically).

This is useful if you want to run a few different scripts and have the environment from all of them at the same time.

Comment: Note that importing in the REPL is not *quite* the same, due to the slight difference in what makes up the `__main__` module.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set `PYTHONINSPECT` in your environment